Cannot install some packages while using pyenv
I found that there are some fails in package installation when I am using pyenv.
I don't know the exact reason, but it cannot find installed modules while installing new package.
For example, when I activate my virtual environment with pyenv activate xxx and try to install the package vamp using pip install vamp, I got the error below even if I installed numpy. (Note that I was using the virtual environment with python 3.8.19)
Collecting vamp
  Using cached vamp-1.1.0.tar.gz (107 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/USER_NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.8.19/envs/ENV_NAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/USER_NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.8.19/envs/ENV_NAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/USER_NAME/.pyenv/versions/3.8.19/envs/ENV_NAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-12igiyji/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-12igiyji/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-12igiyji/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-12igiyji/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

The same phenomenon occurs when I use pyenv shell 3.8.19 instead of pyenv activate xxx
This kind of error also occurs from other packages such as omnizart, madmom, and natten.

Try to run pip as python -m pip.

I think you need to downgrade your python version or upgrade package version ^^
